# Pandas: Dataframe Upsampling Fails for First Period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of daily meteo data, and I would like to replace each daily value with the mean value for the month the day belongs to. To achieve this, I want to first downsample the dataframe to monthly mean, upsample it to daily frequency again. All this using Pandas 1.0.1.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
dframe = 
2001-01-01  23.00000
2001-01-02  19.18034
2001-01-03  9.18034
2001-01-04  0.00000
2001-01-05  0.00000
2001-01-06  0.00000
2001-01-07  0.00000
2001-01-08  0.00000
2001-01-09  9.18034
2001-01-10  19.18034
2001-02-01  20.18034
2001-02-02  10.18034
2001-02-03  0.00000
2001-02-04  0.00000
2001-02-05  0.00000
2001-02-06  0.00000
2001-02-07  0.00000
2001-02-08  10.18034
2001-02-09  20.18034
2001-02-10  24.00000
```

After downsampling, things look alright (values may not be matching, these are dummy numbers):

```
means = dframe.resample(rule = 'M').mean()

means = 
2001-01-31   8.456906
2001-02-28   7.499419
```

But the subsequent upsampling does not work as I would like it to:

```
segmented = means.resample(rule = 'D').bfill()

segmented = 
2001-01-31   8.456906
2001-02-01   7.499419
2001-02-02   7.499419
2001-02-03   7.499419
2001-02-04   7.499419
...               ...
```

The first period (January 2001) is not upsampled, while the second is.

I tried all combinations with the arguments `closed` and `label` and `loffset` and with `bfill()` and `ffill()`, but to no avail; sometimes it's the first month to be wrong and sometiems the last, but there's always a wrong one.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```py
pd.Series(
    [1,2,3,4],index=pd.date_range('2018-01-30', periods=4, freq='D')
).resample(rule = 'M').transform(lambda x: x.mean())
```

This issue with your approach is that when you made `means`, the range of the indexes is no longer inclusive of all the dates you originally had. transform (or apply) is a good way to get the same number of rows back as you put in.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `groupby`, using [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to do it per month and `tranform` like:

```
segmented = dframe.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='M')).transform('mean')
```

assuming the dates are in index, you would have all the dates from `dframe` and the mean over the month associated to each of them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, both answers work perfectly.

" This issue with your approach is that when you made means, the range of the indexes is no longer inclusive of all the dates you originally had "

I suspected something of the sort, but I didn't know how to overcome it.